# Nunit testcontext -> create new dir for every set of logs

Tags: c#, nunit

in I just swapped over from MSTests, where using testcontext.testdir gave me a new folder everytime with user name and th ecurrent time stamp, in NUnit, the same feature "TestContext.CurrentContext.WorkDirectory" points to exact same location every time it goes off... which means the logs I make overwrite themselves every single time I run the tests, is there a simple or rather, fast and sophisticated solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The WorkDirectory is **not** the same thing as the testdir feature of MSTest!

`TestContext.CurrentContext.WorkDirectory` is where NUnit writes report files and is available in case you want to create any reports in your tests. It is set by the `--work` command-line option.

`TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory` is the directory containing the test assembly.

Both are covered in the docs BTW.